# When checkpoint should be added explicitly in SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Scripts we can mention checkpoint right after committing or rolling back the transaction. Although, the SQL Engine implicitly performs the checkpoint activity. Then in what circumstances someone should add a checkpoint statement explicitly in the SQL Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much never in production code.

The only times I think I have used it is

1. Immediately preceding a `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` for test purposes when testing performance with a coldish cache. (The `CHECKPOINT` writes the dirty pages to disc so they are no longer "dirty" and can be flushed by the following command)
2. On a test database in simple recovery model before doing something I want to look at in `sys.fn_dblog` (to truncate the log and make looking at the results easier to follow)

Comment: Then, why this command is there? Just for testing and experimenting? If you could throw some more light.

Comment: I guess for people that don't like the auto checkpointing and want to control when the disc activity happens themselves at least part of the time. I've never found it necessary to attempt to micro manage this aspect myself or heard of anyone doing so. It has been in the product for 25 years, maybe it was more widely used historically –